# How to add/subtract date/time components using a calculated interval?

Tags: teradata

I'd like to get this to work in Teradata:

**Updated SQL for better example**

```
select
case
    when 
        current_date between
        cast('03-10-2013' as date format 'mm-dd-yyyy') and
        cast('11-03-2013' as date format 'mm-dd-yyyy')
    then 4
    else 5
end Offset,
(current_timestamp + interval Offset hour) GMT
```

However, I get an error of `Expected something like a string or a Unicode character blah blah`.  It seems that you have to hardcode the interval like this:

```
select current_timestamp + interval '4' day
```

Yes, I know I hardcoded it in my first example, but that was only to demonstrate a calculated result.

If you must know, I am having to convert all dates and times in a few tables to GMT, but I have to account for daylight savings time.  I am in Eastern, so I need to add 4 hours if the date is within the DST timeframe and add 5 hours otherwise.

I know I can just create separate update statements for each period and just change the value from a 4 to a 5 accordingly, but I want my query to be dynamic and smart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
select
case
    when 
        current_date between
        cast('03-10-2013' as date format 'mm-dd-yyyy') and
        cast('11-03-2013' as date format 'mm-dd-yyyy')
    then 4
    else 5
end Offset,
(current_timestamp + cast(Offset as interval hour)) GMT
```

You have to actually cast the case statement's return value as an interval.  I didn't even know interval types existed in Teradata.  Thanks to this page for helping me along:

http://www.teradataforum.com/l081007a.htm

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you want to multiply the interval by some number.  Believe it or not, that's literally all you need to do:

```
select  current_timestamp                    as right_now
      , right_now +      (interval '1' day)  as same_time_tomorrow
      , right_now + (2 * (interval '1' day)) as same_time_next_day
```

Intervals have always challenged me for some reason; I don't use them very often.  But I've had this little example in my Teradata "cheat sheet" for quite a while.

Comment: I agree with you on the use of intervals. I can never recall how to use them and have to refer to a cheat sheet often.

Comment: I don't want to hardcode the interval value as I mentioned in my question.  I updated my question with a better SQL example.  See if you can get it to work.

Comment: Ahhhhaa!  I figured it out.  Will post as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two remarks:

- You could return an INTERVAL instead of an INT
- The recommended way to write a date literal in Teradata is DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD' instead of CAST/FORMAT

  ```
  select
      case
          when current_date between DATE '2013-03-10' and DATE '2013-11-03'
          then interval '4' hour
          else interval '5'hour
      end AS Offset,
      current_timestamp + Offset AS GMT
  ```